# Has anyone experienced PHPUnit responding with path instead of a test run?

Tags: php, phpunit, mamp

When I run phpunit on MAMP, I only get the following response:
PATH is:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/
```

Has anyone seen this behavior? Is it related to my .bash_profile?

Comment: what are you expecting by this question?

Comment: I've got valid tests that used to run fine in my test suite. Now they do not run. The original install was done with composer, not pear.I've tried the following:reinstall phpunit, reinstall composer, add path to my bash_profile, remove path from my bash_profile. My question to the Stack crowd is whether they've seen this behavior and if there is a fix. I've been using phpunit for 8years and haven't experienced this before.

Comment: put your comment in the question. Otherwise readers get really confused what you are expecting without a clear idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I updated composer, the vendor/autoloader.php was loading an invalid .bash_profile which is why I received the message. I cleaned up the bash file by removing an offending line. Hope it helps someone.